# preg_match is not working on live server, in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to take out only numbers from right side of hyphen `-`

```
$data['last_emp_code'] = 'E-001213231';
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/-(?<number>\d+)/', $data['last_emp_code'], $matches);
print_r($matches['number']);
```

This outputs:

```
001213231
```

The above code is working fine in local server, also it is working on PHP Codepad website when I tested.

```
http://codepad.viper-7.com/fhU4pB
```

I have godaddy host, I can't figure out why this simple code is not working on server.

When I tried to `print_r($matches)` on the server I got empty array.

---

**Update**

Problem was on server, last employee ID didn't had the 'E-' in code. That's why I was receiving error. Local Database and Online Database is different.

Comment: Do you display errors ? And is error reporting on? If not, can you turn them on? Maybe it will give you some clues....

Comment: Do you have a value that you expect in `$data['last_emp_code']`?

Comment: @RahulDesai
Thankyou Rahul. Yes i checked, On server data was not in format of E-(numeric Numbers) for last inserted Employee Code.
Thats why i was getting error for bad entry.

Answer (score 1):

What PHP-Version does your host have? The named patterns (`?<number>`) were introduced with PHP 5.2.2 - perhaps it is not yet there? (Check with `phpversion()`)

Answer (score 1):

Why use preg_match...? do an explode

```
$parts = explode( "-" , $str );
    echo $parts[1];
```

preg functions are like a chainsaw. Use them only when you need to use them. If you can get the same job done with normal C string functions go that way. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

In 95% of those "worked on testsystem but fails on livesystem"-cases it boils down to a different php-version or setting.

Do the `phpinfo()` and check for differences in the version and the settings for the failing part. Some hosts block complete php-functions like `ini_set` or have extensions like `curl` disabled.